# Возможно ли упростить данный код с конструкцией switch

Tags: php, switch

Как можно упростить данный код? Сделать его с одним только switch.

```
<?php
        $day = 1;

    switch ($day >= 1 && $day <= 5) {
     case $day:
        echo "Это рабочий день";
        break;
    }
    switch ($day >= 6 && $day <= 7) {
     case $day:
        echo "Это выходной день";
        break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: У вас  такой код работает ? это очень странное использование switch. Почему бы не воспользоваться `if( $day >= 1 && $day <= 5 ) { рабочий } else { выходной }`

Comment: в том то и дело что надо именно switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $day = 1;
    switch ($day) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
          echo "Это рабочий день";
          break;
        case 6:
        case 7:
          echo "Это выходной день";
          break;
        default:
          echo "Ошибка";
          break;
   };
?>
```

Comment: точно! спасибо!

Comment: мда упростили...

Answer (score 0):

Только если вы уверены, что $day никогда не будет больше 7 и меньше 1 (второе, кстати, гораздо более вероятно)

```
switch($day){
    case 6:
    case 7:
        echo "Это выходной день";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Это выходной день";
}
```